# Alexa Skills Kit: How to call custom intent from another intent in ASK sdk V2

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Hi I have been using and developing skills on Alexa since quite few months. Recently I updated to the ask sdk version 2. I find everything cool and stuck nowhere.

I couldn't find a way to emit an intent now. Like earlier we were able to call Intent from another Intent in following manner:

```
this.emitWithState(<intent name here>);
```

Anybody know how to achieve this in ask sdk V2?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I got the solution. Follow this link: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/391#issuecomment-390944091

Answer (score 4):

Do it as

```js
const FirstIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'FirstIntentHandler';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {

    // some code
    return SecondIntentHandler.handle(handlerinput);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If your skill's interaction model has a dialog model you can do the above by intent chaining. Intent chaining allows your skill code to start dialog management from any intent, including the **LaunchRequest**. You can Chain Intents with Dialog.Delegate as following :

```
.addDelegateDirective({
    name: 'OrderIntent',
    confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
    slots: {}
 })
```

Here is the official release blog of the intent chaining : 
https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/9ffdbddb-948a-4eff-8408-7e210282ed38/intent-chaining-for-alexa-skill

I have also written a sample implementing the same : https://github.com/akhileshAwasthi/Alexa-Intent-chaining

Answer (score -2):

Simply doing

```
this.emit(<intent_name>)
```

will work.

```
const handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function () {
    this.emit('HelloWorldIntent');
  },

  'HelloWorldIntent': function () {
    this.emit(':tell', 'Hello World!');
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is doable in ask-sdk-V1. My question was how to do the same in ask-sdk-v2.

Comment: I got the solution. Follow this link: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/391#issuecomment-390944091

Comment: this is doable in ask-sdk-V1 not in V2